# Get Chart web part to dynamically change with original share point list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, visual-web-part, excel

I have a SharePoint list that contains a list of projects and their technology. Example.

> P1 - Java
>
> P2 - SAP
>
> P3 - Oracle
>
> P4 - Java
>
> p5 - Oracle

I want to be able to represent the Tech distribution in a SharePoint Pie chart WebPart.

The problem I'm facing is that I need to create another table to reflect the actual numbers

i.e.

> Java - 2
>
> SAP - 1
>
> Oracle -2

In excel I would simply create a table that had formulas calculating the numbers so if the techs changed then the pie chart would dynamically change as well.

I'm brainstorming ways I could get the pie chart in SP to change dynamically if the Techs in the first list change or if more projects are added.

Thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can do this with the chart web part - though you may be able to fiddle it if you create a view with counts and then link the web part to the view rather than to the list.

I would be tempted to do this with Excel REST API - that way you can use Excel to define the template of the chart you want and pass the values through to get the chart drawn the way you want it.  There is a basic intro to this at http://paylord.wordpress.com/2013/04/20/excel-rest-meets-xsl/

Comment: Thanks for this Dave, Ill take a look at this, I'm new to share point dev so I'm just trying to look at the various ways of doing this. Happy to explore other options out side of chart web parts.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to create two list:
1. the list that connected to the chart that contain the options and a column  for counting
2. The list that contain the rest of the information 
This link will help you to create a dynamical chart
http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2011/08/04/sharepoint-2010-pie-chart-with-counts-aspx/